# WCF DataContractSerializer and XAML Namespaces

Tags: c#, wcf, xaml, workflow-foundation-4, datacontractserializer

I am sending an object to a WCF service that contains a Windows Workflow definition, but the deserializer is faulting when trying to deserialize my custom activities.

This was previously working when I had the activities' namespaces defined in the form of:

`xmlns:tta="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly"`

but for maintainability reasons I have now mapped my activity namespaces to a XAML namespace using assembly attributes:

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.product.com/activities/", "tta")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.product.com/activities/", "MyNamespace")]
```

Thus my xaml namespace looks like: `xmlns:tta="http://schemas.thacktech.com/activities/"`
And my activity declared as: `<tta:Naptime />`

Because of this change, I now recieve `NetDispatcherFaultException` which reads:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:job. The InnerException message was 'Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Activities:Activity' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'Naptime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null:MyNamespace.Naptime'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'MyNamespace.Naptime' and namespace 'Naptime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

**Questions**:

1. Why does the deseralizer succeed with type resolution when using the clr-namespace syntax, but fail when using the url-style syntax for a namespace declaration?
2. It looks like the type resolver is completely misinterpreting the type, listing the class name as the namespace. Why would it do this?
3. How do I properly implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to serialize XAML as XML? Because it's not.

Comment: Yea, I realize XAML is not the same as XML. I am sending a `System.Activities.Activity` object to the service, and so it should go through the DataContractSerializer, correct?

Comment: "Please see InnerException for more details."  Sigh.  Never *ever* copy just the .Message of an exception.  Call `.ToString()` on the exception object to get the message, type and stacktrace of every exception and inner exception, which is typically needed to pinpoint what's going on.  Also, where's your deserialization code?  And lastly, "I am sending the...object to the service" How are you doing this?  You should probably be serializing to xaml using the activity xaml services, transmitting it as text, then deserializing (assuming  the assemblies exist on the server).